# Can Coda get to my AWS database?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, coda

I've got an AWS EC2 instance, with the usual keypair access technique (and not password access), and am using Coda to do site development on it.  I've been able to configure my .ssh stuff so that Coda can connect to the site's files, and I can see them in the Remote Files pane.  However, I haven't been able to get through to the database.  I'm trying to set up a MySQL pane with "Connect to *MySQL Server via SSH*", but, regardless of what I use for parameters in that panel, I keep getting one varient or another of "The SSH Tunnel has unexpectedly closed."  Has anybody been able to get database access to work?  I've got a phpMyAdmin installation working on the site, but I've kinda gotten use to the Coda interface...  Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used coda, but I have used Sequel Pro to connect to mysql over ssh. You can also configure ssh to create a tunnel for you and then you would connect like you would to localhost.

Comment: Thanks, @datasage.  The issue here (I think) is how to get the Coda interface to ignore the username/password part of the "Connect to server" configuration pane and fall back to the ssh keypair.  It's able to do this for file access, but a similar technique for connecting to the database is still eluding me.

Comment: Technically with an ssh tunnel, you connect both with ssh and then with mysql. You will need both sets of authentication.

Comment: True enough.  Right now, the issue is getting the ssh connection set up via the keypair, since is no username/password combination to put into the form that Coda provides.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use ~/.ssh/config. Use it to create an alias with all your settings (host, port, username, password, private key, etc) and then just point to the alias.

Helpful post: http://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/